# Make a rectangle screenshot from the center of the screen

Tags: vb.net, screen, screenshot, center

I want to know how to take a screenshot from the center of the screen (with a size of 180x100).
How can I do this?

Comment: If you want a code solution I cannot top Mark's answer. However this is what I do. (1) Use `Prnt Scrn` to copy the screen to the scratchpad. (2) Open a new document in Paint, Paint.NET or other image editor of your choice. (3) Paste the contents of the scratchpad into the empty document. (4) Crop the image to the bit I want. (5) Save the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you the image you are looking for. (Edited)

```
Dim Img As New Bitmap(180, 100)
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Img)
g.CopyFromScreen((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2) - 90, _
    (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height / 2) - 50, _
    0, 0, Img.Size)
g.Dispose()
```